# Truncate all relational tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, truncate

I have a relational database in my server where I've used for developing a system. Now I want to make it live and truncate all data from the tables. I've manually deleted data from tables and after that I've run the truncate command, but it show this error :

> Cannot truncate table 'dbo.Building' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Is there any way to empty my database by using a single command? I've searched google, all of them told to use truncate command. But I can not use it for all the tables because the error occurred.

I want to entry data from the ID no 1 in all tables.

Please give me a guideline to truncate all the data from my database.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I want to make it live and truncate all data from the tables

You are approaching this completely wrong. Even if you succeed, you will deploy a system which will be impossible to upgrade. As you continue to develop you will modify the development database and then when you have to deploy your next version of your application you'll realize you need to modify the production database *and* keep all of its data.

Stop the deployment right now and go back to the drawing board to design a proper deployment strategy. [I recommend migrations](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). Another alternative is using diff tools.

Truncating tables is completely irrelevant for what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I could think off..

1. You need to [drop (not just disable ) all foreign keys](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3347/drop-and-recreate-all-foreign-key-constraints-in-sql-server/), then finally run  truncate to delete all table data using any method.. and finally recreate all foreign keys
2. You also can script out only DDL and deploy database using that script instead of providing database to deployment team..